# (CakePHP) isAuthorized related issue. Can anyone please take a look ?

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables in database, Admins and Users. Admins are supposed to open only the Administrator panel for which there are 9 controllers. Users will see the front end for which there is one controller name "HomeController".

When User logs in, he is able to access the Controllers meant only for Admin. And when Admin logs in, he is able to open the Controllers meant only for Users. How do I prevent this ?

AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Admin' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Admin',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                    )
            ),
            'User' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                    )
            )
        )
    )
);

public function beforeFilter()
{

}  

}
```

TransactionsController: (which is to be accessed by the Admin)

```
public function beforeFilter()
{       
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'index');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');

    // Basic setup
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form');

    // Pass settings in
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Admin')
    );

}

public function isAuthorized($admin)
{
    if(isset($admin['Admin']['id']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

HomeController: (which is to be accessed by the User)

```
public function beforeFilter()
{   
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

    // Basic setup
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form');

    // Pass settings in
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form' => array('userModel' => 'User')
    );

    $this->Auth->allow('view', 'index', 'item', 'itemlist', 'search');
}

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    if(isset($user['User']['id']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two levels of authentication, admins and users, you could try [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing):

URLS are predefined

```
http://mysite.com/admin/transactions
```

Which would be routed to the transactions controller where you would have prefixed index methods for each admins and users

```
public function admin_index(){

}

public function user_index(){
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
}
```

If you have more than two user groups, take a look at [Access Control Lists](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)